# SQLite; view; left join two tables; substitute value dynamically with translation from joined table if there is translation in the given language

Tags: sqlite, view, parameter-passing

What would be the view / SQL query, to achieve the thing stated within the title.

**Create code for the involved tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE "books" (
    "bookId"    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "bookName"  nvarchar NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
);

CREATE TABLE "booksLang" (
"bookLangId"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"BookId"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"LanguageID"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"BookName"  TEXT
);
```

**Data in book table:**

```
bookId     BookName
1          Genesis
2          Exodus
3          Leviticus
4          Numbers
5          Deuteronomy
```

**Data in BookLang table:**

```
bookLangId      BookId     LanguageID     BookName_Localization
1               1          12             Genèse
2               2          12             Exode
3               1          10             Schöpfung
4               4          10             Zahlen
```

**Goal:**
The query/view should have the same fields as the book table (BookId, BookName) and always output a row for each record within table books but dynamically substitute the value for BookName from the BooksLang table if there is a localized (translated) version for the given language and same BookId. If there is no substitute, the output value of BookName should be the one from the record in the books table.

**Example:**
If the query to this view looks like this: `select * from <view> where LanguageID = 12`

then the output should be:

```
bookId     BookName
1          Genèse       (substituted from booksLang table)
2          Exode        (substituted from booksLang table)
3          Leviticus    (original from books table because no substitute for given language available)
4          Numbers      (original from books table because no substitute for given language available)
5          Deuteronomy  (original from books table because no substitute for given language available)
```

As I am no SQL expert - How can this be achieved?

**Hint:**
The query below retrieves the desired result when the languageID is provided as part of the left join - but how to do this dynamically from the query which queries this view?

```
select b.bookId, 
(CASE
    WHEN bl.bookName is null
    THEN b.bookName
    ELSE bl.bookname
END) as bookName
from books b left join
     bookslang bl
     on bl.BookId = b.BookId and bl.languageId = 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this view:

```
create view books_langs as
  select b.bookId, coalesce(bl.bookName, b.bookName) as bookName, d.languageId
  from (select id as languageId from languages) d cross join 
  books b left join bookslang bl
  on bl.BookId = b.BookId and bl.languageId = d.languageid;
```

and then query it like this:

```
select bookid, bookname 
from books_langs
where languageid = ?
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aVUYzj2iw6D9XyKdBWmttd/3).

Comment: Is there another table with all the LanguageIDs?

Comment: jup. Create statement for this: CREATE TABLE [Languages] (
 [Id] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
 [LanguageId] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
 [LanguageName] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
) and content: INSERT INTO "main"."Languages" ("Id", "LanguageId", "LanguageName") VALUES ('1', 'en', 'English');
INSERT INTO "main"."Languages" ("Id", "LanguageId", "LanguageName") VALUES ('5', 'de', 'German');
INSERT INTO "main"."Languages" ("Id", "LanguageId", "LanguageName") VALUES ('12', 'fr', 'French');

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aVUYzj2iw6D9XyKdBWmttd/2 . I added a 4th language Italian and when I query with its id it returns all the default values.

Comment: Sorry - you are correct. As long as an existing languageId is chosen, your query works. Have marked your excellent answer as chosen answer and would upvote it further if I could.

Comment: Is there a case that you pass a non existing id in the table Languages?